# AngularJS error injecting module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to develop a login with cookies check if a user is already logged or not.

In order, I include the app:

```
angular.module('ELOAuthentication', [
    'AuthenticationService',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'angular-loading-bar'
])
```

Then the service

```
angular.module('ELOAuthentication').factory('AuthenticationService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

    var service = {};

    service.Login = function (email, password, callback) {
        var Url = '/api/user/GetLoginByEmailPassword';

        $http.then(Url, { email: email, password: password }).success(
            function (response) {
                var data = response.data
                callback(data);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('ERROR GetLoginByEmailPassword: ' + error);
            });
    }

    service.SetCookie = function (email, password) {

    };

    service.ClearCookie = function () {

    };
});
```

Finally the AngularJS controller.

```
angular.module('ELOAuthentication').controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

    AuthenticationService.ClearCookie();

    $scope.init = function () {

    }

    $scope.login = function () {

    };
});
```

I receive the error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

. What is wrong?

Comment: `angular.module('ELOAuthentication', [    
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'angular-loading-bar'
])`  no need to include `AuthenticationService` in here

Comment: Services have to be injected in controllers

Comment: Also, you would have to `return service` at the end of factory.

Comment: and `angular.module('ELOAuthentication').controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http,AuthenticationService) {
    AuthenticationService`  you should add this

Comment: this is some old syntax, but shouldn't `$http.then(...)` be `$http.post(...)` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to inject Services in your module.

*app.js*

```
angular.module('ELOAuthentication', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'angular-loading-bar'
])
```

*LoginController.js*

```
angular.module('ELOAuthentication').controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, AuthenticationService) {

    AuthenticationService.ClearCookie();

    $scope.init = function () {

    }

    $scope.login = function () {

    };
});
```

As mentioned by Sajal, don't forget to return your service object:

*AuthenticationService.js*

```
angular.module('ELOAuthentication').factory('AuthenticationService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

    var service = {};

    service.Login = function (email, password, callback) {
        var Url = '/api/user/GetLoginByEmailPassword';

        $http.then(Url, { email: email, password: password }).success(
            function (response) {
                var data = response.data
                callback(data);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('ERROR GetLoginByEmailPassword: ' + error);
            });
    }

    service.SetCookie = function (email, password) {

    };

    service.ClearCookie = function () {

    };

    return service;
});
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot to all! Still have error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20AuthenticationService`. I don't know why is unknown.

Comment: Did you loaded it in your `index.html`? Something like : `<script src="js/authentication.service.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, load in order:
jquery, angularjs, app, service, controller.

Comment: Do you use a module bundler? Gulp/Grunt/Webpack or other?

Comment: Any bundler: I use VS2017, all lib downloaded by nuget. Is need a .run after the factory?

Comment: Nop. Can you share your HTML?

Comment: No 404 error? I can see an incoherence line 22 & 23 on your scripts load

Comment: Any 404. Console log: angular.js:14525 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20AuthenticationService

Comment: Ok so this is your AuthenticationService that is not loaded (or too late)

Comment: solved: just add .run(function () { }); at the end of my factory :)

Comment: Ok, kind strange if you have to place run there, but glad it works :)